# Appending a line to a file via a ssh chain

Tags: ssh, openssh

From my machine `A`, I got access to a machine `B` that can access a machine `C`.

From `A`, I want to append a line to the file `~/.profile` of `C`.

So far I tried:

```
ssh user@B ssh user@C "echo \"line of text\"" >> ~/.profile"
```

but this way the line is appended to `B`'s `.profile`, not `C`'s one.

Comment: `ssh user@B 'ssh user@C "echo a line of text >> ~/.profile"'`

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk You win!

Answer (score 0):

As well as the answer you got in the question comments, when things get too complex you can simply run bash and get it to execute the commands you provide on standard input:

```
ssh user@B ssh user@C bash <<\!
echo "line of text" >> ~/.profile
!
```